# Find out the nature of the singularity in the given problem?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

At $z = \pi$, the function $f$ defined by $$f(z) = \exp(\dfrac{z}{\sin z})$$ has

1. removable singularity.
2. pole
3. essential singularity
4. None of the above

Comment: i think it is pole as the singularity is isolated and attaining value infinity

Comment: Try to take the limit and remember:
The limit is finite - singularity
The limit is infinite - pole
The limit does not exists - essential

Comment: @gbox So for me limit is infinite.

Comment: @MittalG for real z there is no limit. If $z\to \pi^{-}$ the function goes to $\infty$ but if $z\to\pi^{+}$, for $z>\pi$ the limit is $0$ because the exponent goes to $-\infty$ the function tends to $0$